# How to change value of a local variable inside an inner class?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I just learned that I can't use non-final local variable inside an anonymous inner class so is there any tricky way to do when we need to change values inside inner classes without declaring instant variables?

Comment: You can try and call super

Comment: You can use non-final local variables inside an inner class, but not if they originate from the outer class.

Comment: If it's local non-final variable then it will be destroyed in the end of the method then how can you access it inside the inner class. Either make it final or use instance variable to increase its scope.

Comment: Why there is an issue in making it `final`? share your code.

Comment: There is not issue in making it final. Making it final resolves the error but then you can't change value of variable I want to know is there any other way except declaring instant variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use them for a good reason, which you need to consider before proceeding. What exactly will you do with the instance of the anonymous class? If it is consumed only locally, within that method's scope, then you can use this simple trick (let's say you have an `int` var):

```
final int localVar[] = {1};
new AnonymousClass() {
  public void method() { localVar[0]++; }
};
```

If the instance will be reachable after the method which created it returns, then you may get thread-safety issues. The instance may be passed to other threads and the simple design above is not thread-safe.

Comment: In my code anonymous inner class is reachable after method ends but still this is really tricky thnx

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own very simple `Holder`.

```
/**
 * Make a final one of these to hold non-final things in.
 */
public class Holder <T> {
  private T held = null;

  public Holder () {
  }

  public Holder (T it) {
    held = it;
  }

  public void hold(T it) {
    held = it;
  }

  public T held() {
    return held;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString () {
    return String.valueOf(held);
  }
}
```

Please do not use atomics - they have significant overhead.

```
final Holder<Integer> number = new Holder(0);
... {
    number.hold(n);
}
...
return number.held();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet.

```
void someMethod(){
    final AtomicReference<String> var = new AtomicReference<String>("Blah")
    foo(new Bar(){
        void baz(){
             var.set("Blah-blah");
        } 
    });
}
```